# PyEphem under the hood - how does it calculate position of planets?

Tags: python, pyephem

In space SE it was [suggested](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/13218/12102) I use PyEphem to calculate orbits from two-line elements. Now I'm curious how it calculates "build-in" solar system objects like the planets and their satellites. Does it use one of the standard [JPL ephemerides](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?ephemerides) (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory_Development_Ephemeris)), or something else?

So far I couldn't find out looking at the [PyEphem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/) or [XEphem](http://www.clearskyinstitute.com/xephem/) websites.

For example the JPL ephemerides are generated (loosely speaking) by integrating orbits over a limited period of time while comparing to a large body of observed data to arrive at a set of orbital parameters. Then it is integrated far into the future and past, and results are tabulated at fixed times. This table of positions (and other things) can be called an *ephemeris*.

The ephemeris is then used by interpolating between time periods - in this case using coeficients of Chebyshev polynomials given in the table.

The JPL [DE405](ftp://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/eph/planets/ascii/) ephemeris for example can be read with the python module [de405](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/de405)

@Mattexx has pointed out below that XEphem is using a routine called `libastro`, and that PyEphem is probably doing the same. So I'd like to know what it is using to calculate positions - the algorithm and observed data set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [PyEphem Readme](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem)

> The underlying numeric routines are coded in C and are the same ones
>   that drive the popular XEphem astronomy application, whose author,
>   Elwood Charles Downey, generously gave permission for their use in
>   PyEphem.

The C library is called `libastro`. Inspection of the [libastro source](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/master/libastro-3.7.7/vsop87.c) reveals that it is in fact using VSOP 87.